# Can I create Style Themes in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mono, xamarin.forms

I currently have all my styles in my App.xaml file. Is there a way to group them as a theme so I can multiple app themes and change at will?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I know there is no built-in theming support in Xamarin.Forms but you can implement one.
That you will need to do:
1. Add a number of ResourceDictionaries to your App.xaml with identical list of styles.

```
<Application
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="ThemeTest.App">
  <Application.Resources>
  </Application.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary x:Name="Default">
    <Style x:Key="labelStyle" TargetType="Label">
      <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Green" />
    </Style>
  </ResourceDictionary>
  <ResourceDictionary x:Name="Second">
    <Style x:Key="labelStyle" TargetType="Label">
      <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Yellow" />
    </Style>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Application>
```

2. In your App.xaml.cs add code to switch between styles.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetDefaultStyle();
        MainPage = new TestPage();
    }

    public void SetDefaultStyle()
    {
        Resources = Default;
    }

    public void SetSecondStyle()
    {
        Resources = Second;
    }
}
```

3. In XAML reference your style using DynamicResource markup extension.

```
<Label Text="Test text" Style="{DynamicResource labelStyle}" />
```

I created sample application which you can find [here](https://github.com/halkar/XamarinFormsTheming).
Shell you have any questions you are welcome to ask.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is substituting resources on app start/view initialization. In case you already have a project with Styles and StaticResource references sprawling out for entire project, rather than going and updating all references to DynamicResource, you can create a second XAML dictionary with styles for your theme. One drawback, it might require reloading the app.

E.g. you can have you default theme in App.xaml global resources and white theme style overrides in WhiteTheme.xaml. On creation of the view you can check if the theme is not default (e.g. via *App.Current.Properties.ContainsKey(nameof(WhiteTheme)* ), iterate through all keys in non-default resource dictionary and put/replace with them keys in default dictionary:

```
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            ApplyTheme();

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private static void ApplyTheme()
        {
            if ((App.Current as App).WhiteTheme)
            {
                var whiteTheme = new WhiteTheme();

                foreach (var key in whiteTheme.Keys)
                {
                    if (Application.Current.Resources.ContainsKey(key))
                        Application.Current.Resources[key] = whiteTheme[key];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here're the examples of [App.xaml](https://github.com/maxim-saplin/CrossPlatformDiskTest/blob/master/Saplin.CPDT.UICore/App.xaml), [WhiteTheme.xaml](https://github.com/maxim-saplin/CrossPlatformDiskTest/blob/master/Saplin.CPDT.UICore/WhiteTheme.xaml) and [MainPage.xaml.cs](https://github.com/maxim-saplin/CrossPlatformDiskTest/blob/master/Saplin.CPDT.UICore/MainPage.xaml.cs).